# Java: Run Script After Timed Interval

Tags: java

How do you activate or run a loop every tenth of a second? I want to run some script after an amount of time has passed.

Run a script **every** second or something like that. (notice the bolded font on every)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [TimerTask](http://bioinfo2.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html). e.g.

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
```

You simply need to define a `Runnable`. You don't have to worry about defining/scheduling threads etc. See the [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) Javadoc for more info/options (and [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) if you want *much* more complexity and flexibility)

Comment: Is there a way to use this, but run a script every 1000 milliseconds, rather than just once?

Comment: Possibly re run the script after it runs once?

Comment: You can use scheduleAtFixedRate()

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 1.5:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RepeatedTask(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and

```
private class RepeatedTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

(remember to `shotdown()` your executor when finished)

Answer (score 0):

You sleep.

Check out `Thread.sleep()` but be warned that you probably really don't want your whole program to sleep, so you might wish to create a thread to explicitly contain the loop and it's sleeping behavior.

Note that sleep only delays for a number of milliseconds; and, that number is not a perfect guarantee.  If you need better time resolution you will have to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and do the "time math" yourself.  The most typical scenario is when you run something and you want it to run ever minute.  The time the script runs must be captured by grabbing `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after the script, and then you would need to sleep the remaining `1000 - scriptRunTime` milliseconds.